# Wish they'd change how reputation works

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

I'm tired of seeing stuff like this and dealing with it myself.

This guy gets -5 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752233/get-just-the-first-2-decimal-places-from-a-float-c-sharp (deleted)

Same exact question gets +10 [How to round up a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387873/how-to-round-up-a-number)

Same exact question gets +53 [Make a float only show two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560517/make-a-float-only-show-two-decimal-places?rq=1)

So basically if you search google, and don't find the answer you're looking for, and ask it on Stack Overflow, it's a toss up whether people will decide to vote it up or vote it down. Probably not a toss up though. I bet if your rep is high you can ask any dumb thing and if it's low, you can't even ask good questions because people just look for ways to down vote it instead of trying to help.

I expect a lot of downvotes for this one even though I was directed here to leave feedback, and that's my feedback. There's got to be a better way..

Comment: The two upvoted ones are **old**. I don't think the new one is that bad, but I guess people downvoted because it's a duplicate that _should_ have been found out by a search.

Comment: As a hypothesis with those questions - the first one was downvoted because it was clear the OP hadn't searched SO for the same question. The second one received 10 votes, which isn't too shabby really. The Third post received more because it was from back in 2009 when there were far less questions posted each day so it would have gained more exposure as a result. There's no conspiracy there as far as I can see. Also, I don't really see what your feature request is. It's more of a rant than a feature request. What exactly are you suggesting would be better?

Comment: The more duplicates your question already has on Stack Overflow, the less it is needed there. The older questions have more upvotes because a) It was a less rigorous time b) The question had not been asked on Stack Overflow before.

Comment: Related: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif

Comment: What should change here? Also, people who get downvotes both here and on the main site have a curious tendency to [skip reading the FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: Also worth noting is that these are not the "same exact question". #3 relates to truncating in objective-c, #2 relates to rounding in c#, and #1 relates to rounding+truncating in c#

Comment: So they are all ok. Good point.

Comment: It might also be relevant to mention the tooltip text of the down vote button: *"This question does not show any research effort;"*. If a question has many duplicates which can be found by just searching for the title of the question or related words, then not finding them is clearly a lack of research effort (though I agree it is difficult to find something if you don't know what to search for). I'm pretty sure that often I spend more time finding a duplicate than the OP themselves.

Comment: Jeff's answer is the best. You all should find a way to down vote him. That way you can show everyone how smart you all are and how dumb he is.

Comment: And what made me think of this the first time was when I asked a question about SARGability and got 2 downvotes, then asked the exact same question and got good feedback with no down votes. Those were on the same day.

Comment: I keep finding examples everywhere I go. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282801/textbox-password-char   If that was me or the guy above who got -5, we wouldn't have got 4 upvotes and a comment redirecting us to the older question. We would've got 4 down votes and a comment redirecting us to the other question.

Comment: @IQtheMC you can find all of the examples you want, but the answer is still the same.  People will vote as they want.  The specific question you mentioned was probably downvoted because of the lack of research.  When I google the exact title, the top 3 answers (besides that question) are all SO questions with a solution,

Answer (score 9):

One thing you missed about  those questions is that they're 3 and 4 years old respectively.

You'll find that older questions, even ones that aren't appropriate questions, tend to have a lot of up-votes.

you can actually still see this behavior in some of the smaller, younger SE sites such as https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/ for instance,

there are no questions with a negative score on the front page, in-fact there's only 1 question with a score of 0.

---

When you get to a very large site, like SO, people tend to get irritated of low-quality questions more quickly, and they're more likely to down-vote

Comment: Is that why it requires more reputation points to upvote than to downvote?

Comment: @taz You have that exactly backwards. One need only earn [15 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) to upvote, but [125 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) to downvote.

Comment: @CodyGray It is broken then. I just posted a question that took me down many points, and was no longer able to downvote questions/comments, but was still able to upvote. Edit: I am obviously mistaken and misread your comment.

Comment: Also, I just posted the above comment and it posted as an answer instead of a comment. I deleted the answer and tried again, and got the same result. I refreshed the page and it now appears correctly, so I would guess there are some buggy scripts on here.

Comment: I see now that I accidentally wrote my initial comment backwards. I meant to say "is that why it requires more reputation points to downvote than to upvote?" and, not realizing my error, was subsequently confused by the response.